# Audio click/crackle after period of inactivity with Windows 11

Tags: audio, windows-11

I just built a PC (Windows 11) and I'm noticing a click/crackle when playing audio after a period of silence.

I was able to record an example here, from the Windows volume menu: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iU344ngYjyY

I noticed it start to occur after installing Hyper-V and starting up a Win11 VM. However, the issue has persisted after stopping all Hyper-V services, and even completely uninstalling Hyper-V (+reboot).

I'm using a USB DAC/AMP, and I do not notice the same crackle on another computer using the same DAC/AMP and headphones.

I notice the same crackle when using a pair of bluetooth headphones.

My power mode is set to "Best Performance".

I've tried

- changing the sample rate/bit depth around in the control panel settings
- disabling all other input and output audio devices
- installing the latest Realtek (ALC1220) drivers from my motherboard's (NZXT N7 Z790) support page.
- uninstalling nvidia HD Audio drivers
- disabling XMP
- forcing my GPU (RTX 4070) to use PCIe Gen3
- disabling fast boot

In LatencyMon, I'm seeing issues with dxgkrnl.sys:
[image: LatencyMon report]

Is there anything else I can try?